# How to get ID from td headers in JS or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the id of this td based on the headers' value in order to store it in a variable:

```
<td id="__item105-__clone87_cell1" headers="__text4" style="text-align:left" class="zzzMListTblCell">
```

Comment: Well I've already tried var cell = document.querySelector("td[headers='__text4']"); but it returns the whole thing, not just the id.

Comment: Yes, then you can access `cell.id`

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

the function in jquery to retrieve an id is **.attr('id')**

`$('td').attr('id')`

You have to make sure you're targeting the element properly though.  If you are looping through your td elements you can do something like

```
$('td').each(function(){ console.log($(this).attr('id')); });
```